# Delete MongoDB database from Bash script

Tags: mongodb, bash

I'm not a Bash/Linux person, but I've been asked to just come up with the lines needed to run to authenticate against a database and then drop it.  Here is what I have so far and I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
mongo mydatabase –port –username <username> –password <password> –authenticationDatabase admin –eval “ printjson(db.dropDatabase())”
```

If it's possible to use one line to delete any database whose name starts with "cpt_" then that would be absolutely ideal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -

- Get all the names
- Loop and check if the name starts with `cpt_`
- drop the database

---

```
db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(dbName){ if (dbName.startsWith('cpt_')) printjson(db.getSiblingDB(dbName).dropDatabase())
```

---

Full

```
mongo –port –username <username> –password <password> –authenticationDatabase admin --eval "db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(dbName){ if (dbName.startsWith('cpt_')) printjson(db.getSiblingDB(dbName).dropDatabase())  })"
```